# How to remove a linestring from MultiLineString in OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I can append lineStrings with [appendLineString](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.geom.MultiLineString.html#appendLineString) method. But how to remove them? I tried to [splice](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/splice) them from the getLineStrings array, but without success.

The closest I came was:

```
//multiLineString is my ol.geom.MultiLineString object
multiLineString.setCoordinates([]);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
var multi = new ol.geom.MultiLineString([[[1,2],[2,3],[1,4]],[[2,1],[3,2],[4,1]]]);
var singles = multi.getLineStrings(); //returns an array of 2 LineStrings
singles.splice(0,1);
multi.setLineStrings(singles);

multi.getLineStrings(); //returns a single LineString
```

Comment: But where did you get this setLineStrings method?

Comment: I see that this method is not in the ol3 docs, but it exists in the code (and works!). It was added by this commit https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/commit/0bf34a52ff05cf545c2e32888798d9139c580708 so it has been in the library for a while, and I can't see a reason why it shoulnd't be used.

Comment: This will only work in debug mode, not with the compiled ol.js since it's not part of the API. It's internal.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I didn't realize this as I am compiling my code with closure compiler together with ol3. Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: Oh, it looks like this isn't available. It is just for internal usage. [It isn't exported](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/3700#issuecomment-103476150) -- repeated